# I am not able to enter the data in excel file stored in assets folder in android studio

Tags: android, excel

In the code below I'm trying to read a xls file from assets folder and trying to enter the data into that table through the JXL api, but not able to perform it.

```
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;


import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;

import jxl.write.Label;

public class Event extends AppCompatActivity {

   private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event);

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }


    public void saveevent(View view) throws Exception {

        AssetManager am=getAssets();
        EditText evt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        EditText pth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        try {
            String eventname = evt.getText().toString();
            String eventpath = pth.getText().toString();
```

Here I tried to add locate the file by giving its path.

```
            File f=new File("D:\\DPSRLIVE\\app\\src\\main\\assets\\events.xls");

            InputStream os = new FileInputStream(f);
            Workbook ww= Workbook.getWorkbook(os);
            Sheet ws= ww.getSheet(0);
            /*Label l1= new Label(0,0,eventname);
            Label l2= new Label(0,1,eventpath);*/
            Cell c= ws.getCell(0,0);
            c.equals(eventname); /* not able to insert data*/

            ww.close();

        } catch (NullPointerException n) {

            Toast.makeText(Event.this, "Sorry!! Invalid User name or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Event Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://dpsranipur.dpsrlive/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Event Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://dpsranipur.dpsrlive/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }



}
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Thanks!